# Place DIV over another DIV using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I place a new `<DIV>` exactly over an existing `<DIV>` using jQuery, yet have another `<DIV>` in the existing `<DIV>` appear over the new `<DIV>`?

**Why I wish to do so:**  I have a jQueryUI dialog which contains a tinyMCE editor, and when the tinyMCE editor is opened, I wish to place an overlay over the jQueryUI dialog and disable all click events, yet have the tinyMCE editor appear on top of the overlay and remain active.

http://jsbin.com/sozelafequ

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>jQueryUI Dialog Overlay</title>
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css"></style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#editor',
                setup: function(ed) {
                    ed.on('init', function(e) {
                        e.target.hide();
                    });
                }
            });
            $(function(){
                $('#edit').click(function() {
                    console.log(dialog.parent())
                    dialog.parent().append($('<div>',{id:'blocker',style:"z-index: 100; border: medium none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6; position: fixed;"}));
                    tinymce.get('editor').show();
                });
                $("#open").click(function(){dialog.dialog("open");});
                var dialog=$("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 400,
                    width       : 400, 
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {
                        $('#editor').html('Some data obtained from the DB.');
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='open'>Open</button>
        <div id="dialog" title="dialog title">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="edit">Edit</a>
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a div of the exact same widths over it, which can be done via another div, or use the `:after` selector. If you make you do this via the relative with absolute child, they'll always be the same sizes. Because if `:after` (as uposed to `:before`), it'll be placed over the parent div.

```
#ExampleDiv{
    position: relative;
}
#ExampleDiv:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You could add a class when your button is clicked, and use that class to activate the `:after`.

Comment: Mostly works, however, `yet have another <DIV> in the existing <DIV> appear over the new <DIV>` doesn't.  Please see http://jsbin.com/diyuwujagu

Comment: Please seperate html,js and css. THis is taking to much time to figure out. Also, I suggest you take the `addClass()` method I suggested, a lot cleaner

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn said, use `position:relative` on the existing `<DIV>` and `position:absolute` on the new `<DIV>`.  Also, increase the `z-index` of any elements within the existing `<DIV>` which should be above the new `<DIV>`.

If you disagree with this answer, please indicate why you do.

http://jsbin.com/qifagiducu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>jQueryUI Dialog Overlay</title>
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css"></style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#editor',
                setup: function(ed) {
                    ed.on('init', function(e) {
                        e.target.hide();
                    });
                }
            });
            $(function(){
                $('#edit').click(function() {
                    var dialog=$("#dialog").parent().append($('<div>',{id:'blocker',style:"margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.4; position: absolute;"}));
                    $(this).next().css('z-index',parseInt(dialog.css('zIndex'), 10)+1)
                    tinymce.get('editor').show();
                });
                $("#open").click(function(){$("#dialog").dialog("open");});
                $("#dialog").css('position','relative').dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 400,
                    width       : 400, 
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {
                        $('#editor').html('Some data obtained from the DB.');
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='open'>Open</button>
        <div id="dialog" title="dialog title">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="edit">Edit</a>
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```